# This code keeps returning error that Error: unexpected '{' in: "model <- model {"

Tags: r, bayesian, diagnostics

I am trying to run a Bayesian estimation of the true prevalence, sensitivity and specificity of three diagnostic test; AGID, P-ELISA, H-ELISA. But each time i run the model function it fails. I also need to perform a sensitivity analysis.

I have tried looking into why the code is wrong but could not figure it out. Here is the code I used

```r
c(199, 89, 68, 78, 69, 74, 85, 500),
  agid_sens <- c(41.4, 59.8),
  pelisa_sens <- c(92.7, 100.0),
  helisa_sens <- c(90.9, 99.4),
  agid_spec <- c(98.4, 99.9),
  pelisa_spec <- c(95.1, 99.0),
  helisa_spec <- c(91.4, 96.6),
  prev <- c(0.01, 0.07)
)

# Define the model
model <-
model {
  # Prior distributions
  prev ~ dunif(0, 1)
  agid_sens ~ dunif(0, 100)
  agid_spec ~ dunif(0, 100)
  pelisa_sens ~ dunif(0, 100)
  pelisa_spec ~ dunif(0, 100)
  helisa_sens ~ dunif(0, 100)
  helisa_spec ~ dunif(0, 100)

  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:length(n)) {
    agid_pos[i] ~ dbin(p_agid[i], n[i])
    pelisa_pos[i] ~ dbin(p_pelisa[i], n[i])
    helisa_pos[i] ~ dbin(p_helisa[i], n[i])
    p_agid[i] <- prev * agid_sens / (prev * agid_sens + 
                                    (1 - prev) * (1 - agid_spec))
    p_pelisa[i] <- prev * pelisa_sens / (prev * pelisa_sens + 
                                        (1 - prev) * (1 - pelisa_spec))
    p_helisa[i] <- prev * helisa_sens / (prev * helisa_sens + 
                                        (1 - prev) * (1 - helisa_spec))
  }
}

# Run the model
samples <- bugs(
  data = data,
  inits = NULL,
  parameters.to.save = c("prev", "agid_sens", "agid_spec", "pelisa_sens", 
            "pelisa_spec", "helisa_sens", "helisa_spec"),
  model.file = textConnection(model),
  n.chains = 3,
  n.iter = 10000,
  n.burnin = 5000,
  n.thin = 1,
  DIC = FALSE
)

# Summarize the results
summary(samples)
```

Comment: `model <-
model {` is invalid. Remove the second `model`. However, the assignment doesn’t make sense anyway. Your code is simply assigning `NULL` to `model`, and the braces contain lots of code that does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You use the model in your JAGS run as `textConnection(model)`.  This means that it should be a *character vector*, i.e. surrounded by quotation marks:

```r
model <- "
model {
   ... etc.
}
"
```